# Draw a tensor-like network

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, draw

What are the TeX (TexShop) ways to draw this seemly delicate figure?

[image]

Comment: It seems that you never provide a MWE, and even don't know how to accept  an answer. You are not a beginer after asking 49 questions. For a start you may need `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (-.7,-.7) grid (3.7,3.7); \foreach \i in {0,...,3} \foreach \j in {0,...,3} \fill[red] (\i,\j) circle(2pt);\path (0,3) node[above left]{T};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. Some want to define `pic`s to avoid some of the repetition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,fit}
\tikzset{pics/grid/.style={code={\tikzset{wonderich/.cd,#1}
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wonderich/##1}}%
    \draw[thick] (0.1,0.1) grid (\pv{nx}+0.9,\pv{ny}+0.9);}},
pics/nodes/.style={code={\tikzset{wonderich/.cd,#1}
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wonderich/##1}}%   
    \path  foreach \X in {1,...,\pv{nx}} {
      foreach \Y in {1,...,\pv{ny}} { 
      (\X,\Y)node[minimum size=\pv{r},style/.expanded=\pv{style},inner sep=0pt]{}} };
}},
wonderich/.cd,nx/.initial=4,ny/.initial=4,r/.initial=4pt,
    style/.initial={circle,fill}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.32\textwidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \path pic{grid} pic[red]{nodes}
      (0.3,4.7) node{$\mathbf{T}$};     
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.32\textwidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw[dashed]  pic{grid}
     (0.3,4.7) node{$\mathbf{S}$};
     \clip (0.7,0.7) rectangle (4.3,4.3);
     \path[rotate around={45:(45:2.5)},scale={sqrt(2)},
        shift={(0,-0.75)},transform shape]  pic{grid}
        pic{nodes={style={rectangle,draw,fill=white,rotate=45},r=7pt}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.32\textwidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw[dashed]  pic{grid}
     (0.3,4.7) node{$\mathbf{S}\boldsymbol{'}$};
     \clip (0.35,0.35) rectangle (4.65,4.65);
     \path[rotate around={45:(45:2.5)},scale={sqrt(2)},
        shift={(0,-0.75)},transform shape]  pic{grid={nx=3,ny=3}}
        pic[red]{nodes={r=4pt,nx=3,ny=3}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks +1, can I learn something: It looks that these node commands do not work -- they cannot be compiled.

node{$\mathbf{S}$}
node{$\mathbf{S}\boldsymbol{'}$} 

What may be the reason?

Comment: @wonderich If you load `amsmath` as in the code above it definitely should work.

Comment: Thanks, I loaded all these: but still the compilation stucks at node{$...$}:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,fit}

Comment: @wonderich What happens if you compile the code from the answer as is?

Comment: It outputs:
"See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.56      (0.3,4.7) node{{S}{'}}
                                ;
? 
./1.tex:64: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item."

Comment: @wonderich The above code has 54 lines. If you really get an error concerning l.56, there must be a very big problem in your LaTeX installation.

Comment: @wonderich On the other hand, if you compile the code with [this preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529717/draw-a-tensor-like-network/529728?noredirect=1#comment1339808_529728) you should not be surprised: (plain) `standalone` documents do not support floats like `figure`. Instead of `\documentclass{standalone}` you need `\documentclass{article}` or another document class that supports floats. (This is one of the reasons why users ask for MWEs.)

Comment: thanks you! (I am sorry if I remove the additional preamble), I got this:

Comment: "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/pics/T' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it."

Comment: "See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.27       (0.3,4.7) node{{T}}
                              ;
? 

./1.tex:35: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/pics/S' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ..."

Comment: "l.35      (0.3,4.7) node{{S}}  ;? 
./1.tex:47: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/pics/{S}{'}' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it."

Comment: @wonderich I have no idea what you are doing. All I know is that the above code works fine on my computer. The first thing you want to do is to *copy it as is without modifications* and compile it with `pdflatex`, say. If you then get an error, there is most likely something wrong with your installation, in which case I cannot say anything useful.

Comment: @wonderich I am unable to help you with that since I cannot reproduce any of the issues. The cleanest way may be that you ask a new question with this very code (or any code that you are using) and see if another user can reproduce the problems, and solve them. I have recompiled the code a couple of times, and have updated my TeX installation yesterday, there is nothing more I can do, sorry.